# sending data from angularjs to django

Tags: ajax, django, http, angularjs

I am sending a POST AJAX request using Angularjs and its $http module to Django server. Here is an example:

```
$http({ 
        method: 'POST', 
        url: '/url/', 
        data: 'test data'
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        doSomeStuffWhenSuccess();
  });
```

The problem is what I get in Django. No matter what I send the data is always the key of `QueryDict` object and value of that is always an empty list.

```
<QueryDict: {u'test data': [u'']}>
```

I don't have a clue why. What am I missing?

I use almost default created Django application with default middlewares only. I created only a view and set an url in url config. Version of Django is 1.3. And I configured angular's $http module to always send a header containg csrf token to satisfy Django.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this with jQuery param function. I think it's more elegant solution.

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/url/', 
    data: $.param({test: data})
})
```

Now it works like I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

I believe django thinks you are sending a urlencoded form, ex. key=value&key2=value2...

if you'd try:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/url/', 
    data: 'test=data'
})
```

You should get

```
<QueryDict: {u'test': [u'data']}>
```

You can always obtain the data (raw body content) as follows:

```
request.body
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks this works! But could you explain why django thinks its urlencoded data? And if its possible to customize it?

Comment: request.GET and request.POST contain preprocessed key/value data - if you want raw data (such as JSON or plain text) try: request.raw_post_data