# How to send data as key - value pairs instead of string via POST using XHR

Tags: django, post, xmlhttprequest, angularjs

I'm creating two POST calls. One using a django form and one using angular js via a resource xhr.

The angular setup looks like this:

```
myModule.factory('gridData', function($resource) {
    //define resource class
    var root = {{ root.pk }};
    var csrf = '{{ csrf_token }}';
    return $resource('{% url getJSON4SlickGrid root.pk %}:wpID/', {wpID:'@id'},{
            get: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true},
            update:{method:'POST', headers: {'X-CSRFToken' : csrf }}
    });
});
```

With creating an xhr post request as such:

```
item.$update();
```

This post request is send to the server as expected, but when I want to access the [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) I cannot access the data passed using:

```
name = request.POST.get('name', None)
```

`name` is always `None` like this.

The issue behind this is that the QueryDict object is getting parsed quite strange.

```
 print request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'{"name":"name update","schedule":0"}':[u'']}>
```

Whereas I would have expected this result, which I got when I send the data via a "normal" Post request:

```
<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'name update'], u'schedule': [u'0']}>
```

So it seems to be that Django receives something in the POST request which instructs Django to parse the parameters into one string. Any idea how to circumvent this?

Update:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322561/237690) discussion where they say that the issue is if you provide any content type other than MULTIPART_CONTENT the parameters will be parsed into one string. I checked the content-type send with the POST request and it is really set to `'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`. Thus this is likely the issue. Therefore my question is: How can I set the CONTENT_TYPE for a xhr post request created using angular.js resources to `MULTIPART_CONTENT`?

Comment: you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12191613/1238847

Comment: Thanks. I simply set the header content_type as such 2resulting in the correct content type: 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Unfortunately the params are still transferred in the way I cannot parse them in the view.

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520174/seding-data-from-angularjs-to-django

Comment: In both of the threads they reference to the $.param function of jquery to send the data correctly to the server. Any idea how to include this $.param function into an angular $resource definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could either:

- fiddle with the client to [send data instead of json](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)
- use `json.loads(request.raw_post_data).get('name', None)` (django < 1.4)
- use `json.loads(request.body).get('name', None)` (django >= 1.4)

The Angular documentation talks about [transforming requests and responses](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)

> To override these transformation locally, specify transform functions as transformRequest and/or transformResponse properties of the config object. To globally override the default transforms, override the $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse properties of the $httpProvider.

you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191613/1733117) as was previously pointed at.

Comment: it seems to me as META['QUERY_STRING']) contains the URL parameters and not the POST body parameters. Therefore I think it is not a valid option.

Comment: But when accessing the querydict as you proposed it would work: from django.utils import simplejson as json    name = json.loads(request.POST.keys()[0]).get('name', None)  . Thanks for this hint. Whereas I m still looking for a method to send the data correctly, as this is more a workaround to me.

Comment: `request.raw_post_data` can be used as well.