# How can I send parameters in my http request using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
    data: { applicationId: 3 }
}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.testAccounts = result;
});
```

The code sends the following to my server:

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/Admin/GetTestAccounts
```

When this is received by my MVC controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult GetTestAccounts(int applicationId)
{
    var testAccounts =
        (
            from testAccount in this._testAccountService.GetTestAccounts(applicationId)
            select new
            {
                Id = testAccount.TestAccountId,
                Name = testAccount.Name
            }
        ).ToList();

    return Json(testAccounts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It complains that there is no applicationId.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'applicationId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Can someone explain why the applicationId is not being sent as a parameter? Previously I was doing this with the following non-Angular code and it worked just fine:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
    data: { applicationId: 3 },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        eViewModel.testAccounts(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520174/seding-data-from-angularjs-to-django/

Comment: @Dave - I saw the link you gave me and I am even more confused now :-(

Comment: look at url being used in browser console network tab.. what does it look like?

Comment: @Gemma have you tried using jQuery param `$.param({ applicationId: 3 })`?

Comment: why dont you append application id directly to url in query string

Comment: @Ajaybeni shouldn't have to, and that is not a very practical solution for large data object

Comment: As far as I'm aware HTTP Get doesn't support sending anything in the body of the request and ASP.NET WEB API would expect that parameter in the query. If you want to add parameters to the body you should be using post/put.

Answer (score 31):

If you don't want to use jQuery's $.param you can use $http's param field which serializes an object.

```
var params = {
    applicationId: 3
}

$http({
    url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
    method: 'GET',
    params: params
});
```

Comment: This is angularjs' implementation https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1011

Comment: The url encoding of the params cause trouble for me when Date objects are involved. The serialization pads the Date with the character '%22' (double-quote), which results in the modelbinder of WebAPI/MVC failing to deserialize the Date.

Comment: I've filed an issue on Github for this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8150

Comment: This is fixed in 1.3.16

Comment: This was not fixed for Moment.js. So be sure to use .toDate() if you use it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I will try to answer this.

I think the problem is that angularjs presume that data passed to http will be urlencoded. I am not sure why angular doesn't serialize it implicitly if there's an object. So you have to encode it yourself:

```
 $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
       data: 'applicationId=3'
       })
```

or use jQuery param to encode it for you:

```
$http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/Admin/GetTestAccounts',
     data: $.param({ applicationId: 3 })
     })
```

Comment: jQuery's implementation: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/80538b04fd4ce8bd531d3d1fb60236a315c82d80/src/serialize.js#L15
Angular's implementation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1011

Comment: Based on their discussion of `angular.extend()` I would guess they don't like to implement deep copy and the like.

Comment: Equally, you could implement a shallow API query design or use JSON requests

Comment: You don't use `data` in a `GET` request, you use `params`

Comment: Getting Error: $ is not defined near $.param